# laravel cashier - save creditcard last 4 number and expire date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using laravel 5.2 with cashier package
this is the form that i'm using in order to get the client creditcard token:

```
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="test_token"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

after it the form is submitted automatically And i get the regular answer from the server that contain the client token.

How i can save the credit-card last 4 number and expire date that the user enter?
I Know that i don't need it for credit card transactions. i just want to save it in order to show it to my customer which card thy entered.

Thank!

Comment: Do you even have that data in the response? Can you post the whole response you get from the company?

Comment: I don't think its possible, and would advice against storing any data on your server. Each country has different rules (about storing credit card information) - legal wise. By using stripe your customers are assured that no information is stored on your server.

Comment: On the contrary, I don't think saving last4 and expiration is bad practice. When you work with stripe they let you have that data very easily.

Comment: Why store them at all when you don't need that information?

Comment: I Know that i don't need it for creditcard transactions. i just want to save it and to show it to my customer which card thay entered

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need it.

If you look at [Laravel's Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/billing) documentation, you just pass a credit card token when [creating a new subscription](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/billing#creating-subscriptions):

`$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($creditCardToken);`

So you don't need the last 4 digits or expiry date, just the token (which you already have).

Comment: I Know that i don't need it for creditcard transactions. i just what to save it and to show to my customer which card he enter